# Problem not receiving new information in Telegram robot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have created a robot with the python telegram bot package that receives information from the database and sends it to the user.
The information stored in the database is the price of a digital currency (received within 30 seconds of the new price and stored in the database)

Now when I run the robot in the server, it responds to commands without any problem in Telegram, but the problem is when the first command is sent in the robot, it receives the information from the database and sends it to the user, and in the next steps, the user re-commands Enters the robot uses the same information as before and does not receive new information

```
import logging
from uuid import uuid4
import emoji
import mysql
import mysql.connector
import telegram
from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, ParseMode, InputTextMessageContent, Update, InlineKeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram.utils.helpers import escape_markdown

dbpares = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="phpadmin",
    password="123456",
    database="pares"
)

cursor = dbpares.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM algo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
algoData = cursor.fetchone()
algoPrice = algoData[1]



def human_format(num):
    num = float('{:.3g}'.format(num))
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.0
    return '{}{}'.format('{:f}'.format(num).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), ['', 'K', 'M', 'B', 'T'][magnitude])


def convert_num(number, points):
    decimal = pow(10, points)  # power function

    return number / decimal


# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

    update.message.reply_text("Hi dear user" + "\nYou can use /chart command for get tokens information \nexample: \n`/chart 470842789`" , parse_mode='MarkdownV2')


def chart(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    try:
        update.message.reply_text("Price: " + algoPrice)
        cursor.close()
    except:
        update.message.reply_text("No data found for this asa ☹")
        cursor.close()


def inlinequery(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Handle the inline query."""
    query = update.inline_query.query

    if query == "":
        return

    results = [
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(uuid4()),
            title="Caps",
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query.upper()),
        ),
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(uuid4()),
            title="Bold",
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                f"*{escape_markdown(query)}*", parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN
            ),
        ),
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(uuid4()),
            title="Italic",
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
                f"_{escape_markdown(query)}_", parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN
            ),
        ),
    ]

    update.inline_query.answer(results)


def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('chart', chart))
    # on non command i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(inlinequery))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Block until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not receiving new information because you aren't requesting for it. `algoPrice` will always be the same since it's only executed once my suggestion would be to move `algoPrice` or whatever is generating the new data to your `chart` function. Unfortunately I'm not vast in SQL.